# Finding max values in a text file read in using Python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file containing only numbers. There are gaps in the sets of numbers and the problem asks that the file is read through, adds the numbers within each group then finds the top three values in the list and adds them together.
I've found the way to read through the file and calculate the sum of the largest set but cannot find the second or third.

I've pasted my code here:[my coding attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nfn5.png)
and my results text file content here: [List of values in the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8IvG.png)

Comment: Don't post your code as images, please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to store the group totals.

Read the file a line at a time. Try to convert each line to int. If that fails then you're at a group separator so append zero to the group_totals list

Sort the list and print the last 3 items

```
FILENAME = '/Users/dan/Desktop/day1 copy.txt'

group_totals = [0]

with open(FILENAME) as data:
    for line in data:
        try:
            group_totals[-1] += int(line)
        except ValueError:
            group_totals.append(0)
    print(sorted(group_totals)[-3:])
```

**Output:**

```
[740, 1350, 2000]
```

**Note:**

This code implicitly assumes that there are at least 3 groups of values